# UWP Secure Local Storage

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

When using [local storage](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/#JlDrBidDZME3EI18.97) in UWP, once the app has been published, can the user who installs the app tamper with the saved settings from classical desktop or command line?

It seems to me that this could easily be done. Is there a way to securely store settings and data within the app, without using a remote service and cryptography? In other words, is there a system API that allows this?

For example, the [Store-Managed Consumables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-consumable-add-on-purchases) allow managing in-app items securely. However, there doesn't seem to be anything similar for general settings. How would one go about storing randomly generated ids for products or in-app keys and items?

Comment: What is the threat you're trying to mitigate? Note that the user can just attach a debugger to your program as well and mess with it at runtime...

Comment: I understand this, but it requires significantly less knowledge to navigate File Explorer to the app's Local or Roaming folder and modify a file, than it does to debug the app without code. The solution I have in mind is to simply encrypt the file or the settings entry. I was just enquiring whether it was possible to do this through some integrated API I did not know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect data at rest, you can use the [`DataProtectionProvider` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider). It will stop casual users from seeing your data, and if they modify it then your app won't be able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to securely store settings and data within the app,without using a remote service and cryptography?

For your requirement, you could use **Roaming data** to store the app setting data, Roaming data for an app is available in the **cloud** as long as it is accessed by the user from some device within the required time interval.

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
roamingSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello World";
// High Priority setting, for example, last page position in book reader app
roamingSettings.Values["HighPriority"] = "65";

// Composite setting

Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
    new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
composite["intVal"] = 1;
composite["strVal"] = "string";

roamingSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"] = composite;
```

For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

Comment: The user can still tamper with this from command line, if I'm not mistaken. I want to hide the stored setting from the user (even if they are a power user). I can use a certificate to encrypt the settings, but is there a simpler method, provided by the platform?